# VSTO Outlook Addin (Member not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020003 (DISP_E_MEMBERNOTFOUND))) Error while deleting attachment

Tags: vsto

I am adding a contact thru Right Clicking a Outlook contact --> Forward Contact--> As a Business Card. . This will add a .vcf file as a attachment and a embedded image in the mail body. when user clicks my Addin i have to delete the .vcf attachment and provide a custom link to the user.

Now the problem is when i try to delete the attachment i am getting this Exception:

```
Member not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020003 (DISP_E_MEMBERNOTFOUND))
```

I get this exception only if i do Right Clicking a Outlook contact --> Forward Contact--> As a Business Card.  If i drag and drop any file then i don't get any Exception while deleting that attachment.

As I am new to outlook plugin I am not sure where I am going wrong. Any suggestion would help me a lot.

Comment: What property or method fires the exception?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use any low-level property viewer tool such as MFCMAPI or OutlookSpy for observing properties. You can also may try to delete the attachment there. Do you get any errors in that case?